# Laravel process multiple jobs at the sametime

Tags: php, laravel

I am making an api that requires the job to be dispatched multiple times, however, each job takes 10 seconds, and it takes forever to process one by one. Is their anyway to run multiple job once?

```
GetCaptcha::dispatch($task_id)->afterCommit()->onQueue('default');
```

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve that by running multiple workers at the same time.

From the Laravel docs:

> To assign multiple workers to a queue and process jobs concurrently,
> you should simply start multiple queue:work processes. This can either
> be done locally via multiple tabs in your terminal or in production
> using your process manager's configuration settings. When using
> Supervisor, you may use the numprocs configuration value.

**Read more here:**

https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/queues#running-multiple-queue-workers
https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/queues#supervisor-configuration

Comment: Yes with multiple workers we can reduce the time it takes to process jobs. But is there a way to assign an individual worker to user? or any better solution which can help reduce the time it takes to process 10k jobs in a minute?